# Operator matrix norm associated with the vector norm

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces

What is the operator matrix norm associated with this vector norm?

$$\Vert x \Vert = \frac{1}{n} \mathop {\sum} \limits_{j=1}^{n} \vert x_j \vert, \qquad (x \in \mathbb{R^n})$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be the same as the operator norm you get for the usual $1$-norm up to a factor.

In particular, if $A=(a_{ij})$ is $n\times m$, then
$$
\|A\|=\frac nm \max_j \sum_{i=1}^m |a_{ij}|
$$